# Handle tab press for any HTML element in jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm building a Screen Reader and I'm wanting to navigate through HTML elements on the page using Tab and Shift+Tab presses.

So far, I've got the following code, which works fine:

```
$('a, input, button').keyup(function(e) {
    // code
});
```

However, the problem I have is the above code will only work for a tags, inputs, and buttons. If I want to add code for a span, or a summary tag, I would have to change the code to:

```
$('a, input, button, span, summary').keyup(function(e) {
    // code
});
```

I was wondering if its possible to re-write this so that it handles every HTML element. I tried something  like:

```
$('*').keyup(function(e) {
    // code
});
```

But that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Add the event listener to highest level container you need this to work in and check the `target` of the `event`. Providing some sample html would help get a more constructive answer as per [mcve]

Comment: You may want to look into how existing screen readers do it; they don't tab to every element on the page; blind readers don't care about the `i` element thrown in there for an icon since they can't see the icon anyway. There is more to creating a good screen reader than just tabbing to things, just as there is a lot more to creating an accessible web site than having a good tab order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Reflective for their contribution. Using parts of their answer, I've formed the below, which works:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.key == 'Tab') {
     console.log($(e.target).text());
  }
});
```

You can then use the `$(e.target)` to access what you want from the current element.

Answer (score 1):

Please first read about event propagation. Your event (if not stopped by `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`) will be spread to all parents, so it's absolutely enough to do the following.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    // code
});
```

Of course you can catch the event on any other level if you need to handle the event on some area but not on whole document. Here's an example of that case when just A1 and A2 buttons wrapped in `.containerA` div will be handled.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.containerA').keyup(function(e) { 
    if (e.key == 'Tab') {
     console.log($(e.target).text());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="containerA">
  <button>A1</button>
  <button>A2</button>
</div>

<div class="containerB">
  <button>B1</button>
  <button>B2</button>
</div>
```

Talking about the tabbing, you probably need to capture on focus event, but that's not clear so I will stop with this immediate answer of your question.